# A bash shell program to wait for all servers in a list to start, then run startup scripts

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to automate the startup (after reboot) of an application that runs on a grid of 12 Linux 7 servers.

The 12 servers get rebooted in random order.

All the servers need to be running before I can start up the application that resides on the 12 servers.

What I'd like to do is to test that all 12 Linux 7 servers are up and then when all 12 are up, I'd proceed with the startup sequence of commands.

All 12 server are set up with ssh keys.

cat serverlist.txt
     10.0.0.6
     10.0.0.7
     10.0.0.8
     10.0.0.9
     ...
     10.0.0.18

I want to ping a server and then wait until the ping is successful, then move to the next IP address.

My apologies for my question.

How to code this?

Read in the first line from IP list file.
Ping first IP until success, then ping the other IP addresses (one at a time) until the success of all 12.

Then, run commands to start the application on the grid of 12 servers.

Question: How to code this in the bash shell.

Comment: Fixing issues that http://shellcheck.net/ can identify automatically is probably a good place to start. Beyond that, I don't see a well-formed question here -- "doesn't work" isn't really a useful description of a specific and narrow problem.

Comment: One thing I *would* suggest doing is encapsulating your healthcheck code in a shell function. That way you can run `if myfunc; then ...`, and let `myfunc`'s definition worry about what's involved in checking a server's health and availability (in doing which you'd probably be better off testing the simple stuff -- say, `ping` -- before bothering with something higher-level like SSH).

Comment: (Then again, I'd also advise against trying to roll your own code for this in the first place when there are plenty of battle-tested, widely-deployed higher-level infrastructure tools that have primitives for the kinds of actions you're looking for built in... often, already integrated with higher-level tooling like Chef/Puppet/Salt/Nixops/etc. out-of-the-box).

Comment: BTW, is there any point to `cd ~ >>/tmp/test.log &` instead of, `ssh "$i" true`? No heredoc needed at all that way. (Not that that's really an adequate is-this-server-fully-booted? test -- I'd be querying systemd for that -- but the extra complexity in the current check doesn't appear to serve any obvious purpose).

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop can be as simple as

```
while ! ssh "${connection_string}" -o ConnectTimeout=5 true
do
    sleep 0.5
done
```

This runs a trivial command, and waits for 0.5 seconds between retries.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `cat /home/Startup/serverlist.txt`
do
    ssh ${i} -o ConnectTimeout=5 true
    while test $? -gt 0
    do
        ssh ${i} -o ConnectTimeout=5 true
    done
done
exit
```

If ssh works the server is alive, plus the use of the timeout is a better way to speed up the script execution. If the script get finish that means all the servers are up and responding.

Comment: `for i in $(...anything...)` is bad form; it relies on string-splitting, which has undesired side effects like glob expansion. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) re: best practices for reading from a file in bash. (The initial bad practice is also covered as part of [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29); see the paragraph just before "So, what's the right way to do it?").

Comment: ...and `test $? -gt 0` is silly -- **all** `if` statements test a command's exit status. Here, you're running `ssh`, letting its exit status go to `$?`, then running `test`, and checking `test`'s exit status. Why not just check `ssh`'s exit status directly in the first place, and avoid the `test` call altogether?